# Make javascript continue to play after redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, master-pages

Im using visual studio 2013. Coding in .net c#.

My projekt is a CMS where im using Master page.

On content pages i got a save button. When pressing that i load a javascript from a class with this code:

Contentpage

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Sys.Enigma.Message m = new Sys.Enigma.Message();
     m.InfoMessage("Post is updated", 5, Master.Page);
}
```

Class

```
public class Message
{
    public void InfoMessage(string text, int seconds, Page page)
    {
        seconds = seconds * 1000;
        text = "<div class='e-info-message'>" + text + "</div>";
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "<script type=text/javascript> var x = document.getElementById('e-info-message'); x.innerHTML = \"" + text + "\"; setTimeout(function() { $('.e-info-message').fadeOut('slow');}, " + seconds + "); if (isPostBack){$('.e-info-message').show();} </script>");
    }
}
```

What happends is that i display a div with green background with "Post is update" in it. It automaticly fades out after 5 seconds. But if i redirect the user to any other page or the user clicks any other link in the CMS the div dissapears.

I want the div to be visible for x seconds even if page is redirecting or user clicking other links inside the CMS.

Ive been searching and trying loads of stuff for 2 days now without getting it to work. So this is a working example for non redirect / user clicking any link.

Anyone who has any idea how to get this to work the way i want it to?

Comment: you can't.  Once the user clicks away from your site, the page is gone, period.  That would be akin to having a web browser still display your div even after being shut down...you're trying to override the behavior of the browser.  What might work for you, however, is that you change everything BEHIND the div.  That way, you're still on the same page, but you've "reloaded a different one" into view

Comment: Just a thought, all content pages loads from master page contentholder.

Any idea to make only contentholder content to update after postback/redirect? Maybe updatepanel?

Comment: yes, but when you go to a new page, the page still reloads...everything you see gets blown away and is recreated.  Master pages are essentially just a template system

Comment: Alright, if you know any other way to make "admin messages" to appear the way i want it, maybe cookies or something, feel free to point me to the right direction.